# iOS force App to use custom keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-app-extension, uiinputviewcontroller

I am working on the app which has a one `text-field` which should accept only `numbers` so I created one `custom keyboard` which has only `[0-9]` as input to accept.To use this `custom keyboard` one has to go  `setting`-->`keyboards` then accept this and then open particular keyboard from the app.

Is this possible to force user to open only `custom keyboard` without going into setting option. I want whenever user opens the app.. **only** `custom keyboard` should open, not other

Comment: Why not make it numeric by default?
UITextField *numericTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 185, 30)];
numericTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
numericTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[parentView addSubview:numericTextField];

Comment: wy dont u set  `_textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` for this textfield the keyboard shows only number pad

Comment: @Shan I want to set the custom keyboard for iOS8 not the apple's default keyboard

Comment: @user3226440: What we're trying to ask is: Is there any specific reason you want to re-invent the wheel? There already is a numeric keyboard, so why do you want to implement your own?

Answer (score 1):

Just make it numeric by default. You could also do that from interface builder.

```
UITextField *numericTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 185, 30)]; 
numericTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 
numericTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; 
[parentView addSubview:numericTextField];
```

Source: [How do I programmatically switch keyboard layouts on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071765/how-do-i-programmatically-switch-keyboard-layouts-on-the-ipad)

EDIT:
Or your could use the NSNotificationCenter to inform you whether a keyboard is called and simply call your own instead:

Try something like this, didn't try myself though:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Hi. I want to set the custom keyboard which i created for iOS8. not the Apple default keyboard..

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can this using this code just make a view of your custom keyboard and add this line to show your keyboard instead of default keyboard

```
numericTextField.inputView = your_keyboardView;//here your_keyboardView is the object of the custom keyboard view.
```

`UITextField *numericTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 185, 30)];
numericTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 
numericTextField.inputView = yuor_keyboardView; 
[parentView addSubview:numericTextField];`

If you have any query then please let me know.